# Is there a (nontrivial) known example of an algebra over a complete regular local ring with the following property?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

I am working on some algebras over complete regular local algebras. But I am not sure whether such rings are worth to study. I am looking for some examples of these algebras. Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a complete regular local ring. Is there any (nontrivial) example of an $R$-algebra $\Lambda$ which is finitely generated and maximal Cohen-Macaulay as an $R$-module, with the property that every $\Lambda$-module which is maximal Cohen-Macaulay as an $\widehat{R}$-module is locally projective on the puctured spectrum of $R$?
More gemerally, Let $R$ be a Henselian regular local ring. Let $\Lambda$ be an $R$-algebra with infinite global dimension which is finitely generated and CM as an $R$-module. I am looking for an example of such algebra with the property that every $\widehat{\Lambda}$-module which is $MCM$ as an $\widehat{R}$-module is locally projective on the punctured spedtrum of $R$.Is there any axample of such algebra where $R$ is not complete?

Comment: Are you considering some version of "complete Cohen-Macaulay" that applies in the non-Noetherian case?  If your local ring is Noetherian of finite global dimension, then it is regular.  Is there a reason that you do not just say that $R$ is regular?

Comment: You are right. I added the global dimension condition in the final step and I didn't notice that this ring is a regular local ring and o it is CM. But can we give an example of an algebra as above with infinite global dimension? I mean, I am looking for an algebra with the above properties    with infinite global dimension over a complete regular local ring.